# OOP JavaScript: Call method from inside of Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop, methods

I'm building a jQuery app using OOP principles and I'm trying to implement a externally added callback function which invokes a method from inside of my object.

```
function testObject() {
    var self = this;

    var functions = new Array();

    this.updateObject = function() {
        console.log('updated')
    }

    this.addFunction = function(func) {
        functions.push(func)
    }

    this.callFunctions = function() {
        $.each(functions, function(key, value) {
            functions[key]()
        })
    }
}



var myobject = new testObject();
myobject.addFunction(
        function() {
            $(':text').on('change', function() {
                return self.updateObject();
            })
        }
)
```

This is an overly simplified version of the plugin I'm building. The callback works fine, but I cannot use the self.updateObject(); inside of it, since it outputs Illegal Invocation.

How can I call a method from inside the callback properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `self` is out of scope of the callback function, because the function only has variables in the scope of where it was defined. The callback is defined outside of the `testObject`.

A solution is to bind the `this` context in the callback function to `self` using [`Function.prototype.call(self)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), when you call it in `callFunctions()`. Then in the callback, you can use `this` to refer to the `testObject` instance. In your callback example it contains a jQuery event so you will lose the `this` context. To rectify that you can create a local `self` that equals `this` before the jQuery change event.

```
function testObject() {
    var self = this;

    var functions = new Array();

    this.updateObject = function() {
        console.log('updated')
    }

    this.addFunction = function(func) {
        functions.push(func)
    }

    this.callFunctions = function() {
        $.each(functions, function(key, value) {
            functions[key].call(self); // call it and bind the context to self
        })
    }
}

var myobject = new testObject();
myobject.addFunction(
        function() {
            var self = this; // needed because the change event will overwrite 'this'
            $(':text').on('change', function() {
                return self.updateObject(); // use self to access testObject
            })
        }
)
myobject.callFunctions();
```

---

Alternatively you can pass `self` as an argument to the callback. To do that, change the `.call()` line to:

```
functions[key].call(null, self);
```

and change the callback to accept an argument like so:

```
myobject.addFunction(
        function(self) { // self as an argument
            $(':text').on('change', function() {
                return self.updateObject(); // use self to refer to testObject
            })
        }
)
```

Comment: Hi MrCode! Thank you very much for your complex answer. I'm still getting the same error unfortunately. Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation. I've tried calling it in many ways, and it doesn't work, even though it theoretically should.

Comment: Edit. I got it right the first time. The problem was in the updateObject() method which was calling a method illegally. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
function testObject() {
    var self = this;

    var functions = new Array();

    this.updateObject = function() {
        console.log('updated')
    }

    this.addFunction = function(func) {
        functions.push(func.bind(self)) // Bind the context
    }

    this.callFunctions = function() {
        $.each(functions, function(key, value) {
            functions[key]()
        })
    }
}

var myobject = new testObject();

myobject.addFunction(
        function() {
            var self = this;

            $(':text').on('change', function() {
                return self.updateObject();
            })
        }
)
```

Or you can use this as well:

```
 myobject.addFunction(
            function() {    
                $(':text').on('change', this.updateObject);
            }
    )
```